# Control-M: it is possible if first job fails to continue running

Tags: control-m

I have several jobs than will run in sequence. It is possible to create a dependency between them only for completion, but not that the prior job has to complete successfully?

If a job fails this should remain red and go to the next job and continue running.
It is mandatory that this jobs to run in sequence and not in paralel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, on the actions tab you create and On/Do step and say when Not OK the job should add the output condition. In this way the next job will run (in sequence) regardless of what happens to the predecessor job.

Comment: But is there a way to keep the job that ended not ok with color red? And then go tobthe next job?

Comment: If i select WHEN JOB ENDED NOT OK to SET TO OK, the job will become green

Answer (score 3):

As Mark outlined you can simply create an On-Do action within the parent job to add a condition when the job ends Not OK. The parent job will still go red and the successor job will kick off.

See below for an example:

[image: On-Do Action]

Comment: Hi. I tried this way but the current job became red and tho flow stoped. I want to continue runnig.

Comment: What was the next job in the flow waiting on? It’s conditional requirements should have been satisfied by the condition that was posted by the on/do step.

Comment: It just says wait condition.   
I have 5 jobs that run in sequence and for each job i ve added exactly what you have in the screenshot.

Comment: In the name field you are putting the actual condition name right? As in it should not read “CONDITIONFORNEXTJOB” - that’s just placeholder text.

Comment: Can you give me an example with a condition?

Comment: If you right click on the waiting job and select “waiting info” it will tell you the exact condition name that it’s waiting on. This is the same name that should be configured in place of “CONDITIONFORNEXTJOB”.

Comment: I don't know what am i doing wrong... i copied the condition from the next job and added to the current job in name field from on add action.. but it doesn t work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172156/discussion-between-florentinap-and-joobear).